# PHP5-FPM and MYSQL

Tags: mysql, lighttpd, php

I'm using lighttpd and pfp-fpm.
All work correctly, but if I call a mysql_connect() on my php scripts I get an empty page.
Like a "denied operation".

This is my php-fpm.conf pool

```
[example.com]
        listen             = 127.0.0.1:9001
        listen.backlog         = -1

        user  = example.com
        group = example.com

        pm                   = dynamic
        pm.max_requests      = 0
        pm.max_children      = 2
        pm.start_servers     = 1
        pm.min_spare_servers = 1
        pm.max_spare_servers = 1

        chroot = /home/vhosts/example.com/

        request_terminate_timeout = 2
        request_slowlog_timeout   = 1
        slowlog                   = /home/vhosts/example.com/log/php-slow.log

        catch_workers_output = yes

        env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
        env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
        env[TMP] = /tmp
        env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
        env[TEMP] = /tmp
```

This is my lighttpd vhost:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|.)example\.com$" {

        server.document-root = "/home/vhosts/example.com/web"
        server.errorlog      = "/home/vhosts/example.com/log/error.log"
        accesslog.filename   = "/home/vhosts/example.com/log/access.log"


        fastcgi.server = (
                        ".php" => (
                                "localhost" => (
                                        "docroot" => "/web",
                                        "host"    => "127.0.0.1",
                                        "port"    => "9001"
                                )
                        )
        )

}
```

What is wrong? If I don't use mysql I can see the result of the php script correctly.

Comment: Check your server's (lighttpd) error logs (/home/vhosts/example.com/log/error.log)

Comment: mysql_* functions are considered obsolete and are not enabled by default, hence mysqli was introduced and later on PDO. If you want to use mysql_* functions, you need to load the proper .so in php configuration.

Comment: @egis @Michael J.V. If i comment chroot option I can use mysql correctly. I think there are some problem with that. NO?

Comment: I found a problem....2011-05-02 13:09:54: (mod_fastcgi.c.2711) FastCGI-stderr: PHP Warning:  Unknown: open(/var/lib/php5/sess_e2r45va7j72t19gv084va3gl56, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php5) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /web/inc/classes/mysql.class.php on line 26

Answer (score 1):

Turning on error display and posting those errors would be helpful, but since you can use mysql without chrooting php, I guess you are getting some connection error, since php tries to connect to mysql on localhost using socket ( php compiled with `--with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql.sock`), and most likely this socket is outside your chrooted environment.

You can try:

- Recompiling php to not use socket
- creating hard link to socket in your chrooted path
- using some internal ip (like 10.0.0.1,192.168.0.1) instead of loopback

Comment: env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
        env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
        env[TMP] = /tmp
        env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
        env[TEMP] = /tmp
Could be useful ? I can set the mysql and php paths ?

Comment: Whyy internal IP and not 127.0.0.1:MYSQL_PORT ?

Comment: According to the documentation you can also use 127.0.0.1. I thought that both `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` were mapped to local socket.

Comment: Do i have to change mysqld.socket with the local ip address on any php.ini directives or on my.cf ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me all the problems are because of the user and group being example.com
i guess that user doesnt have rights to perform the requested tasks